# How to crossfade images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working script to fade one image in, then out, then the next in, then out, etc.

My goal is to crossfade the next image into the current image while it fades out, but when I call .attr("src") its interrupting the fadeout and fading in the next image abruptly.

Any ideas?

Code:

```
var aImages = new Array();
var iPrev = -1;
var iRnd = -1;

aImages[0] = "images/image1.jpg";
aImages[1] = "images/image2.jpg";

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("img#bg").load(function()
        {
            $("img#bg").fadeTo(3000,1);

            setTimeout(function() 
                {
                    $("img#bg").fadeOut(3000);
                    setTimeout(LoadImages,3000); // <-- when this value is decreased to attempt to crossfade them it messes up
                }
                ,5000);
        }           
    )

    setTimeout(LoadImages,0);

});

function LoadImage(iNr)
{
    $("img#bg").attr("src", aImages[iNr]);

};

function LoadImages()
{
    while(iPrev == iRnd)
    {
        iRnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*aImages.length);
    }

    LoadImage(iRnd);

    iPrev = iRnd;

};
```

Comment: You will need two `<img>` elements that overlay each other.

Comment: yeah Bergi was right. you need two img and then process them at the same time.

Comment: Yup not sure why I didn't think of that. Works great. :)